# Page jumps to the top onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a click in the middle of a website with code like `<a href=“#“ onclick=“…`

The function works well, but the a href=“#“ let’s the page always jump to the top when I click on the link. Is there any way around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Just add `; return false;` to the end of your `onclick`, for example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hello'); return false;">
```

**Edit**: Hemlock's answer is a good alternative, but yet another one is a combination of the two:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('hello')">
```

The advantage of this is that you're explicitly saying that the `<a>` should do nothing with the href, and the onclick event handler is a separate attribute. If you later decide to attach the onclick handler using JavaScript rather than inlining it (recommended), it's simply a matter of removing the onclick attribute.

Comment: `href="javascript:"` works for me too. Is it not the same as `javascript:void(0)` ?

Comment: @Nikita good question, I haven't seen just "javascript:" but it appears to work. I don't have IE to test with at the moment though.

Comment: Wouldn't href="javascript:" be like declaring this is javascript and the not running anything and when you add void(0) it runs the void function which does:"The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 4):

Alternate method

```
<a href="javascript: alert('hello'); void(0);"></a>
```

Put the javascript in the href and make sure the code ends in a call to `void`

Answer (score 2):

add

```
return false;
```

at the end of the onclick statement

that is

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('test'); return false;"> Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want an element that does some javascript `onclick`, you should not use the `a` tag. The `a` tag is for navigation from one page to another. You should use `span` and then you don't have to provide a `href` attribute. The problem lies in the fact that you chose the wrong HTML element for your case.

```
<span onclick=""></span>
```

Comment: The reason to use a focus-able element for click is for keyboard navigation, required for accessible sites. A user can tab to an a element to focus, and press enter to 'click' it.